# Как в fullcalendar вызвать onclick по клику объекта

Tags: javascript

Я хочу чтобы по клику срабатывала функция как ссылки в htlm

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="startAjax('karban.php');karban();">Создать</a>
```

Как это сделать в календаре?

```
  eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        onclick= "startAjax('infor.php?id=+ calEvent.id +')";

    }
```

Спасибо

Comment: Вы его используете без framework? И что у вас не получается? Какие ошибки? Из вопроса ничего не понятно.

Comment: Я спрашиваю как правильно вызвать => onclick= "startAjax('infor.php?id=+ calEvent.id +')" это грубый пример

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы поставить обработчик событий на элемент — то есть указать какая именно функция будет выполняться при нажатии на него — используйте `addEventListener`, например:

**HTML:**

```html
<span id="link">Создать</span>
```

**JS:**

```js
var elLink = document.getElementById('link');
elLink.addEventListener([событие - в вашем случае 'click'],[функция],false);
```

Рекомендации:

1. Не стоит писать css свойства в style: html и css должны быть в разных файлах.
2. Не стоит использовать обработчики событий при помощи html атрибутов, js и html должны быть разделены.